# Need some best practice opinions

Tags: xpages

I'm creating an XPages application that will display a view that lists all the software applications at our site by name.  I've got the application name displaying as a link, but I don't want to open the document from the view when someone clicks on the link.  Instead, I'd like to read a field on the underlying document that contains a URL and launch it.  This URL could launch a Notes Client application, an Xpages application or just a web site.

What is the best way to retrieve the URL and launch it when the user clicks the link?  What are the gotchas for each URL type?

Thanks,

MJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct your link as HTML. Lets say your field with the URL is called `targetURL` and your application name field is `Subject` then you do a computed column type HTML (so no escaping) with:

```
"<a href=\""+curRow.getColumnValue("targetURL")+"\">"+curRow.getColumnValue("subject")+"</a>"
```

You would have the fields in the view (but you don't need them in the view control)

Comment: Why construct the HTML your self if there is an property called pageurl which does this for you?

Comment: Ther is always more than one way to skin a cat. I would expect the PageURL to be a field a user edits and just puts in the url http ftp mailto notes sap etc. as "seen on screen". Of course you could compute a field "page link" that has the full a href in it, but that only would invite potential for getting out of sync. The pageURL also can be used e.g. in RSS or automated eMails where you don't necessarily want a plain a href around them

Comment: Don't do this if curRow.getColumnValue("targetURL") or curRow.getColumnValue("subject") can contain user submitted information, it opens up the potential for cross site scripting attacks. This is particularly important for the href attribute as I don't think the Active Content Filter will catch the javascript: url scheme in this case.

Comment: Lorcan, you are right. I presumed here, that sanitization of input happens at the time of saving the information (where it should be) :-)

Comment: #stwissel I'm not sure where you mean to contruct the link. Do I put it in the onclick event?  Also, does it automatically launch or is there some command that launches it?

Comment: Mike you add a column to your view and specify it as computed column (in data) rather than picking a column from the view. If you use a repeat control instead of a view control you would use a computed field. As Lorcan pointed out, you need to make sure the URLs are sanitized before you save them.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting close.  Where do you declare the curRow variable.  I can't find a place to enter a Collection Name.  Also, not real sure what you mean by sanitize.

Comment: @stwissel When I run it I get this error:Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=21: [ReferenceError] 'curRow' not found

Comment: curRow is the variable name I usually specify in the view control for 'var'. It gives access to the current row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the view control click on the view column and there is a property called pageUrl. Give your view control a collection name like rowData. You should be able to compute this (click on the little diamond next to the property) by using something like rowData.getColumnValue("mycustomurl"). This assumes there is a column in your view called mycustomurl that contains the url you want to link to.

I do not know about the different URL types I have not tried them launched from and Xpage yet.

Hope this helps,

Elijah

Comment: In other words what he said. Just kidding slightly different way to do it. :)